# Find distinct value from dataframe column and create new column in datafrase and set frequency in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have sample dataframe like

```
_id    Dept    Result
1234    dept1   NaN
1235    dept2   Good
1235    dept2   Bad
1235    dept2   Good
1235    dept2   none
1235    dept2   none
```

I want to convert it into

```
_id     Name   Good Bad none
1234    dept1   0   0   5
1235    dept2   2   1   2
```

I am able to do it with `for loop`. As I have too much data so using for `loop` is slow, need some optimised solution. Can it be achieved by using some dataframe function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and for prevent remove `None` column replace `NaN` and `None`s by same value, e.g. `non`:

```
df = pd.crosstab([df['_id'], df['Dept']], df['Result'].fillna('non'))
print (df)
Result      Bad  Good  non
_id  Dept                 
1234 dept1    0     0    1
1235 dept2    1     2    2
```

Comment: is it possible to replace that NaN with Some constant integer? ant it should be under `none` column

Comment: @HiteshGhuge - Sure, use `.fillna(1)` for replace by `1`

Comment: I am newbie with this, So another silly requirement as I can see `fillna()` adding new column but i want `NaN` under `none` column with some constant value

Comment: I am able to achieve this by `df.loc[df.non == 1, 'none'] = const`